# FatSecret REST KIT issue with GTMOAuth

Tags: objective-c, ios, rest, oauth, restkit

I'm trying to work with FatSecret Rest API and GTMOAuth, but I dont know whats wrong.
Does anyone with experience that can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I'm new to Objective-C so please be patinent.

```
- (void)sendRequests4
{
    NSString *consumerKey = @"my consumer key";
    NSString *sharedSecret = @"my shared secret key";

    RKClient *client = [RKClient sharedClient];

    GTMOAuthAuthentication *auth = [[GTMOAuthAuthentication alloc]
                                    initWithSignatureMethod:kGTMOAuthSignatureMethodHMAC_SHA1
                                    consumerKey:client.OAuth1ConsumerKey
                                    privateKey:client.OAuth1ConsumerSecret];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:client.baseURL];

    auth.shouldUseParamsToAuthorize = YES;
    [auth addAuthorizeTokenParamsToRequest:request];
    [auth addAuthorizeTokenHeaderToRequest:request];

    // Perform a simple HTTP GET and call me back with the results
    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [params setValue:consumerKey forKey:@"oauth_consumer_key"];
    [params setValue:kGTMOAuthSignatureMethodHMAC_SHA1 forKey:@"oauth_signature_method"];
    [params setValue:auth.timestamp forKey:@"oauth_timestamp"];
    [params setValue:auth.nonce forKey:@"oauth_nonce"];
    [params setValue:@"1.0" forKey:@"oauth_version"];
    [params setValue:@"??????" forKey:@"oauth_signature"];
    [params setValue:@"foods.get_most_eaten" forKey:@"method"];
    [params setValue:@"??????" forKey:@"oauth_token"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://platform.fatsecret.com/rest/server.api"];

    NSString *sigSecret = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&", sharedSecret];

    NSString *sig = [OAHMAC_SHA1SignatureProvider signature:params
                                                     AndURL:url
                                              AndHTTPMethod:@"POST"
                                         AndSignatureSecret:sigSecret];

    NSString *encodedSignature = [sig urlEncodeUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [params setValue:encodedSignature forKey:@"oauth_signature"];

    [client post:@"foods.get_most_eaten" params:params delegate:self];
}
```

Thanks alot!

Comment: I didn't fixed it. just used something else.

Comment: What else did you use? Isnt there a way we can configure the RKClient object properly to make this request? No matter what I try, my response is empty. Moreover I do not know why the response is empty! That is the big problem.

Comment: Let me check it and get back to you with an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like random mixture of two separate OAuth 1 libraries, OAuthConsumer and GTM OAuth,  that were not intended to be used together.

Answer (score 1):

The OAuth negotiation was pretty difficult to get running, so I open-sourced our company's solution if you're interested.

https://github.com/mysterioustrousers/FatSecretKit